# How should I structure my AngularJS routing to handle URL rewriting and page refreshes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-rewriting

I'm building my own website using AngularJS. I want my site's navigation to behave without the "browser flash" that exists when you go between pages, e.g. clicking a link on `index.html` that takes you to `foo.html`. I also want clean URLs, so for instance I can go to `mysite.com/foo` and have the browser display the content in `foo.html`.

Angular's client-side routing in HTML5 mode is an effective solution, but there are exceptions:

If I go to `mysite.com`, I can configure `$routeProvider` to map the view to the appropriate partials (e.g. `index.html` or `foo.html`) and modify the URL the browser displays. However, if I go to `mysite.com/foo` by directly typing that URL into the browser, I will get a 404 error because the server is looking for something in `mysite.com/foo/` that isn't there. The same will happen if I refresh the page while Angular is pointing to `mysite.com/foo`.

In short, navigating to `mysite.com/foo` is only handled properly if navigated from within the Angular app.

How can I handle this so that my site behaves the way I want? Do I use PHP and/or `mod_rewrite` to redirect the browser back to `mysite.com` upon 404?

In essence, I want the URL `mysite.com/foo` to display the `mysite.com` view + the `foo.html` partial *whether the URL is set by Angular or manually typed in the browser URL bar*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need something like mod_rewrite.

http://ericduran.io/2013/05/31/angular-html5Mode-with-yeoman/